# What's the "toss you for it" wager Jake Green makes in the casino?

Tags: revolver

During the opening of Revolver, Jake Green (Jason Statham) enters Dorothy Macker's (Ray Liotta) casino. After proceeding up the elevator, he enters the high rollers' private room and makes two wagers, losing the first and winning the second, much larger, wager, made against Macker.

Jake says "I'll toss you for it", declares a color (red the first time, purple the second), then flips one of the casino's chips to determine the outcome. What exactly are they betting on? Are the chip faces different colors? It didn't appear so to me, but they aren't exactly central in any of the shots.

Additionally, is this a reference to [Kerry Packer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerry_Packer)? There's a parallel story about him, and "Kerry Packer" is quite similar to "Dorothy Macker".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are betting on the colors of the chip. One side of the chips is mostly purple, [image]

while the other is red.

[image]